# How to use Financial Dimension owners in an AP workflow [AX 2012]?

Tags: workflow, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

It's my first time trying to setup an AP Invoice approval workflow. When an invoice comes in, ultimately, we'd like to use the financial dimension information on the project to identify who the account owner is, so that they can approve it.  We really only need this workflow for project-related invoices.

Thus far, I've seen that hierarchies are available, but not really applicable to this scenario.  We have a hierarchy-based workflow in use for the purchase requisition approvals -- but looking at that one hasn't illuminated an answer.

Any ideas or can someone point me to a specific resource that shows a little more about *how* to set it up would be most helpful and appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this programming related?

Comment: I'm not sure!  I mean, technically, workflows can be setup without any customization -- but since I don't know how to accomplish what I'm asking, programming could be needed.  If there is a better place to post, please let me know and I'll ask my questions there. :)

Comment: Start here: https://workflowax.wordpress.com/